# package sun.net.www.protocol.https is declared in module java.base, which does not export it

Tags: java, eclipse, build.gradle

I am trying to build a java project using gradle6.6 and open jre 11.0.2, in eclipse 03-2020.
I am facing compilation issue, while building my project which uses the classes from jrt-fs.jar; e.g.'sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler', which is in open jre 11.

```
public class Manager extends sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler{
(package sun.net.www.protocol.https is declared in module java.base, which 
 does not export it)
 1 error
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Following is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

allprojects {
      apply plugin: 'java'
      sourceCompatibility = '11.0.2'
      targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

repositories {
      mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
      compile group: 'org.hamcrest',            name: 'hamcrest-all',     version: '1.3'
      compile group: 'junit',                   name: 'junit',            version: '4.10'
      compile group: 'jmock',                   name: 'jmock',            version: '1.0.1'
      compile group: 'com.google.code.findbugs',name: 'findbugs',         version: '1.3.9'
      compile group: 'cglib',                   name: 'cglib',            version: '2.1'    
      testCompile group: 'junit',               name: 'junit',            version: '4.10'
 }
```

also, how can I avoid building the test classes, through gradle?

Comment: `sun.*` and `com.sun.*` packages are internal to the implementation, not documented, and not guaranteed to remain present or compatible. Sun and then Oracle have been telling everybody not to use them for 30 years, and modular java (9 up) finally starts to enforce that rule (by not exporting them, as it says). And no, this class is NOT in jrt-fs.jar. Your code needs to be fixed.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks for your comment :-), yes, it needs to be fixed. Also, facing issue of  ":compileTestJava symbol:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dave_thompson_085 suggested, Issue is due to modular restriction (JDK-1.9 onwards) on sun.net.* packages , as they are internal to JDK. The above packages are accessible in JDK -1.8. We need to fix our code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gradle, add this compilerArgs in build.gradle

```
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    options.incremental = true

    options.compilerArgs.addAll([
            "--add-exports",
            "java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http=ALL-UNNAMED"
    ])
}
```